# Why is different between typeof Function.prototype and typeof Fn.prototype?

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Why is different between typeof Function.prototype and typeof Fn.prototype?

```
function Fn() {}

typeof Function // 'function'
typeof Fn // 'function'

typeof Function.prototype // 'function'
typeof Fn.prototype // 'object'
```

it's very confusing for me

Comment: Did you try to just print `Function.prototype` and `Fn.prototype` to see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of a function will be a plain, empty object unless something is done to change that.

You (the author of the `Fn` function) did nothing to change that when you created the `Fn` function.

The authors of the `Function` function set a different value to be the prototype.